# not submit form until slow ajax jquery is completed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

The ajax jquery I am using in my form takes almost 4 seconds to complete and create the fields I want in my form. Because of that, some users submit the form before those fields are created. I want the form not submitted until those fields are created.

Here is my code.

```
echo"<form action='http://teachers.teicm.gr/dvarsam/index.php/exelixi_aitisis/' method='post' onsubmit='return recaptcha();'>
    <label class='formLabel'>Όνομα*</label><br />
    <input name='FirstName' required='' type='text'/><br />
    ...
    ...
    echo"<select name='ThesisID' id='link_block'  onchange='showCourses(this.value)'>
        <option disabled='disabled' selected='selected' value=''></option>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value= {$row[Thesis_ID]}>{$row[Thesis_Title]}</option>";
        }
    echo"</select><br />";

    //displays the courses when thesis is selected
    echo"<p id='courses'></p> ";

    //placeholder which you’ll need to add to your form markup wherever you want the reCAPTCHA to appear
    echo"<div class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='6LcIzA4TAAAAABo7Ean4z9EbNJddkkh04x9v6pLs'></div>

    <input  type='submit' name='action' value='Αποστολή' />
</form>";
```

On submit function. It checks if receptcha "I am not a robot" is clicked

```
function recaptcha () 
{
    if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == ""){
        alert('Παρακαλώ επιβεβαιώστε ότι δεν είστε ρομπότ κάνοντας κλικ στο κουτάκι.');
        return false;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

OnChange javascript. It shows textboxes on < p id='courses'>

```
//Browser Support Code
function showCourses(str){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Problem with your browser!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

   // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
   // and will update div section in the same page.
   ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('courses'); // the div section where it should be displayed
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    // Now get the value from user and pass it to server script.
    var queryString = "?thesis_id=" + str ;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", "http://teachers.teicm.gr/dvarsam/index.php/get_courses" + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

I think that I need to add something in my on submit function that will return true only when the ajax jquery is completed. Am I thinking correctly? Can someone help me with that?

Comment: You should probably start with sticking with one form: Or vanilla javascript or jQuery. Using both, but especially jQuery, it will be easy to for example disable the submit button and enable it when the delaying request has finished.

Answer (score 0):

First, give an ID to your submit button and disable it by default:

```
<input  type='submit' ID="SUBMITBUTTON" name='action' value='Αποστολή' disabled />
```

Then you can do something like this in your On Success return from Ajax to enable the submit button:

```
$('#SUBMITBUTTON').removeAttr('disabled');
```

OR

```
$('#SUBMITBUTTON').prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: This sounds like a good answer. Just a little stupid question. Where exactly should I put the $('#SUBMITBUTTON').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: I tried both ways but none of them worked. I placed the code in my script after ajaxRequest.send(null);